# X11.app (on SnowLeopard) won't start

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xorg, macports

Today I discovered that X11.app no longer works on my Mac. I'm not sure when this happened. I think it's been several weeks since I last used an X11 application.

By "no longer works" I mean it does *absolutely nothing*. If I try to run X11.app directly, nothing appears in the dock and there is no error message -- it's as if I didn't run it at all.

If I try to run an X application from the Terminal (eg: xterm) it just hangs forever. I assume it's waiting for X11 to start up.

I tried reinstalling X11 from the Snow Leopard install DVD, and that doesn't seem to have had any effect.

**Update**

I have MacPorts installed and it looks like `xorg-server` may have been
installed. I tried uninstalling it...

```
port -u uninstall xorg xorg-server
```

...and reinstalling it...

```
port install xorg xorg-server
```

...but either way things don't work.

Here's what `/var/log/system.log` shows when the MacPorts xorg is
installed.

```
Dec  1 14:28:26 Stripy org.macports.X11.stub[51551]: Xquartz: bootstrap_look_up(): Unknown service name
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51470]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51470]: xinit: giving up
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51470]: xinit: unable to connect to X server: Operation timed out
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51470]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections xinit: server error
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51470]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy defaults[51670]: \nThe domain/default pair of (org.macports.X11, dpi) does not exist
Dec  1 14:28:27 Stripy org.macports.startx[51638]: xauth:  file /Users/laurence/.serverauth.51639 does not exist
Dec  1 14:28:28 Stripy org.macports.startx[51638]: 
Dec  1 14:28:28 Stripy org.macports.X11.stub[51723]: Xquartz: Unable to locate waiting server: org.macports.X11
Dec  1 14:28:28 Stripy org.macports.X11.stub[51727]: Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/MacPorts/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
Dec  1 14:28:30 Stripy org.macports.startx[51638]: ^M
Dec  1 14:28:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[51638]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 14:28:48: --- last message repeated 8 times ---
```

This repeats over and over, (modulo time stamps and pids).

Here's what t looks like when the MacPorts xorg is not installed.

```
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy defaults[64771]: \nThe domain/default pair of (org.macports.X11, dpi) does not exist
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: xauth:  file /Users/laurence/.serverauth.64738 does not exist
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:·
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: xinit: unable to run server "/opt/local/bin/X": No such file or directory
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: Use the -- option, or make sure that /opt/local/bin is in your path and
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: that "/opt/local/bin/X" is a program or a link to the right type of server
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: for your display.  Possible server names include:
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:·
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xquartz     Mac OSX Quartz displays.
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xvfb        Virtual frame buffer
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xfake       kdrive-based virtual frame buffer
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xnest       X server nested in a window on another X server
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xephyr      kdrive-based nested X server
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xvnc        X server accessed over VNC's RFB protocol
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:     Xdmx        Distributed Multi-head X server
Dec  1 14:55:32 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:·
Dec  1 14:55:34 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]:  xinit: giving up
Dec  1 14:55:34 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Dec  1 14:55:34 Stripy org.macports.startx[64737]: xinit: server error
Dec  1 14:55:34: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

Again, this repeats over and over.

I also tried uninstalling the macports `xorg` and then installing
XQuartz (and again, rebooted to be sure). Running
Applications/Utilities/XQuartz doesn't work, nor does trying to run
`xterm` from Terminal, Here's the output of `/var/log/system.log` with
that setup:

```
Dec  1 16:13:01 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 16:13:01 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[400]: Xquartz: bootstrap_look_up(): Unknown service name
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: giving up
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Operation timed out
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections /opt/X11/bin/xinit: server error
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[343]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy defaults[544]: \nThe domain/default pair of (org.macosforge.xquartz.X11, dpi) does not exist
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[510]: xauth:  file /Users/laurence/.serverauth.511 does not exist
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[510]: 
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[588]: Xquartz: Unable to locate waiting server: org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Dec  1 16:13:02 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[589]: Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
Dec  1 16:13:03 Stripy login[619]: USER_PROCESS: 619 ttys000
Dec  1 16:13:04 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[510]: ^M
Dec  1 16:13:06 Stripy org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[510]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
Dec  1 16:13:22: --- last message repeated 8 times ---
```

(Once again, repeating.)

I've tried searching for some of these messages, and found a couple of
hits but no concrete solutions.

Comment: Have you tried [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/)?

Comment: No. I'm open t trying it out, though I'd like to know why the stock X11 is failing.

Comment: @ephemient I have now tried XQuartz, and also MacPorts' `xorg-server`, and none of these configurations work. Please see the update to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

X11 on OS X requires a pair of `launchd` `plist` files to be active; this pair must match, and also must be configured correctly at `login` time.  Each of the X11 servers provides its own pair:

- for Apple's X11, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.x.privileged_startx.plist` and `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.x.startx.plist`;
- for MacOSForge XQuartz, `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist` and `/Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist`;
- for MacPorts XQuartz, `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.privileged_startx.plist` and `/Library/LaunchAgents/org.macports.startx.plist`.

It's quite common for these to get mixed up when multiple X11 installations are present.  Best bet is to disable all of the startx LaunchAgents with `launchctl unload -w`, then enable only the one you want to use with `launchctl load -w` (the `-w` tells `launchctl` to remember the action for subsequent boots/logins).  Do not unload the LaunchDaemons.  It is necessary to log out and back in after this in order for the DISPLAY environment variable to be set correctly.

Comment: I should mention we're currently hashing this out on FreeNode IRC; the above is apparently not the complete answer.

Comment: I've finally managed to fix this. It turns out that my `.bashrc` was doing something screwy. I still don't know why this would cause X11 to break in the way it did.

Comment: If it is .bashrc then it is possible that you break your $PATH variable.

Comment: You should NOT disable any of the privileged_startx jobs.  You need to have all of them loaded, but you probably want only one of the startx jobs loaded.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar. My .profile was 'source'ing my .bashrc and my .bashrc had an ancient test for interactivity:

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && exit`

Changing the "exit" to a "return" did the trick for me.

Comment: I literally only recently added something similiar to prevent some slow options I only wanted loaded under special conditions.  Unfortunately it broke a lot more than I could have expected.  Your note helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My .profile had `exec bash` at the end (to ensure that the .bashrc is executed). This was the reason why X11.app was not able to start.

After changing this to `. .bashrc` X11.app starts fine again.